# Remove a marker in google maps API V3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

in an app building environment I'm trying to use this code:

```
   var map = new Appery('googlemap').gmap;

var markerLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(localStorage.getItem("markerLat"), localStorage.getItem("markerLng"));
var Titolo = 'Some Title';

var markers = [];

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: markerLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: Titolo,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
});
markers.push(marker);


function setAllMap(map) {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].setMap(map);
  }
}




google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {markers.pop();
  map.refresh(); 
                                                          setAllMap(map);
                                                          });
```

but it doesn't works. Could anyone say me why? I just want to remove the last marker that the user made by clicking on any marker she/he wants.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the marker object from the array will not remove the marker from the map. You have to call *setMap(null)* on the marker to do so. Just do *markers[markers.length -1].setMap(null)* and then *pop()* on the array;